# sqoop import command issue with partition key

Tags: hive, sqoop, sqoop2

I am trying to import data in hive table using sqoop command. The hive table is partitioned by date2 and date is in the format of "9/6/2017 00:00:00". It's throwing error when I use sqoop command to import data using the date column.

Teradata table :
column1, date2, column3 
1,9/6/2017 00:00:00, qwe
2,9/20/2017 00:00:00, wer

**Sqoop command:**

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:teradata://<server>/database=<db_name> \
--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager \
--username un \
--password 'pwd' \
--table <tbl_name> \
--where "cast(date2 as Date) > date '2017-09-07' and cast(date2 as Date) < date '2017-09-20'" \
--hive-import --hive-table <db_name>.<tbl_name> \
--hive-partition-key date2 \
-m1
```

**Error**

> ERROR teradata.TeradataSqoopImportHelper: Exception running Teradata import job
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Wrong FS: /usr/tarun/date2=1900-01-01 00%3A00%3A00

Comment: I have created an external table in hive making partition with date2 column.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried translating your command to multiline, it looks you have missed one \ character and that's why it looks it is complaining. --hive-import is not ending with "\". The hive table name is also missing in the command

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:teradata:///database= \ 
--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager \
--username un \
--password 'pwd' \
--table \
--where "cast(date2 as Date) > date '2017-09-07' and cast(date2 as Date) < date '2017-09-20'" \
--hive-import \
--hive-table tarun121 \
--hive-partition-key date2 \
-m1
```

alternate to this is to try create-hive-table command

```
sqoop create-hive-table \
--connect jdbc:teradata:://localhost:port/schema \
--table hive_tble_name \ 
--fields-terminated-by ',';
```

let me know if this solves the issue.

Comment: Hi Roy. I was able to run the code without partition key successfully. But the error is with the partition key date2 . That's where it shows error.